# Встретила в контексте слово "свойство-функция". Что это значит?

Tags: javascript

Встретила в контексте слово "свойство-функция". Что это значит?

Comment: "в контексте" - ??

Comment: @Igor Да, в контексте.

Comment: @ioioioi, в каком контексте?

Comment: @Grundy в контексте javascript

Comment: @ioioioi, покажи конкретное место где именно ты увидела "слово"  _"свойство-функция"_

Comment: @ioioioi Может вы имеете ввиду "Свойства функции"?

Comment: @Grundy Каким образом?

Comment: @ioioioi, например дать ссылку на место где ты это встретила.

Comment: свойство-функция - метод?

Comment: @WVFFLIFE Все-таки метод. Синоним к слову метод?

Comment: Да, это метод. Свойства бывают у объектов, например, в том числе это свойство может быть функцией. В итоге это метод называется.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Похоже что речь идёт об объектах. В данном случае *свойство-функция* - это **метод**